# Filtering based on container numbers on an indexed variable

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, winlims

I am using a User-Defined SQL statement to import data form a database which is connected to Microsoft Access called WinLIMS. I am trying to count the number of container numbers and only show records for those which have counts that are `> 6` (i.e., count those records which have the same container number and only show the container number counts which are larger than 6).

I do not want to include null values and I have tried moving my `count` function to the `Where` clause and using a `HAVING` clause (which gave me an "error too few parameters expected...>1" for the first solution attempted and an "error in TRANSFORM statement" for the second solution attempted).

The code is calling items from a database WinLIMS™ which is then referenced through Access™, but I was told SQL code (general) will work.

We use the `TRANSFORM` statement to normalize our data due to slow servers. `[REG_ON]` is a `DATE` and `[CONTAINER_NO]` as well as `[CONTAINER_NO_FIXED]` are text values:

```
TRANSFORM Min([ORESULT])   

SELECT  [REG_ON], [COMMINGLED_LOT], [MKT_SYNONYM], [CONTAINER_NO],
```

This is the part of code where I am removing things such as hyphens and extra spaces, as they still should count as the same container with or without special characters values such as `[CONTAINER_NO]="T-164"` and `[CONTAINER_NO]="T164"`

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
([CONTAINER_NO]," ","")," ",""),"_",""),"51400","51A400") AS 
[CONTAINER_NO_FIXED], COUNT([CONTAINER_NO_FIXED]) AS   
[CONTAINER_COUNT],      

FROM [dbo.V_NWA_RESULT]          

WHERE [REG_ON]>=DATE () - 360 AND [MKT_SYNONYM] IN 
("6860", ""4459")            

GROUP BY [REG_ON], [COMMINGLED_LOT], [MKT_SYNONYM], [CONTAINER_NO], 

HAVING [CONTAINER_COUNT] > 6 PIVOT [PA_NAME]  IN   ("Aluminum (Al)",
    "Antimony (Sb)",      "Arsenic (As)",       "Barium (Ba)",
    ....       //This is done to normalize data since our server is slow
```

In summary I would like this list to exclude containers `51A400`, `51A200`, `GC1`, and `51A988` (note -- used snippet of data, and this would only be true if I used greater than 1 instead of 6, but this is just for clarification).

[image: screencap of results]

Thanks

Comment: You are asking for suggestions to revise a query, which is not here?

Comment: @TallTed The query is written above the table

Comment: Oh, I see, you've interjected question blurb in the middle of your query.  The query does also appear to be incomplete, as you've got commas before `FROM` and `HAVING` ... which can cause various errors, if this is as-executed.  I suggest you provide Query1, Q1Error, Query2, Q2Error, Query3, Q3Results, description of what is unexpected about Q3Results.

Comment: @TallTed Thanks I will update this question accordingly and apologize as I am very new to all of this thanks!